# generating random numbers using threads

Tags: c, multithreading, random, pthreads

I'm trying to generate a number of random floats between -1 and +1, the total amount is specified by the user as well as the amount of threads, the total amount of random numbers is then split equally between threads, the threads all use one workspace struct.

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

typedef struct WorkspaceStruct {
    unsigned int tid;
    int points_generated;
    int points_in_circle;
    unsigned int seed;
}Workspace;

void *worker(void *ws) {
    Workspace *workspace = (Workspace *) ws;  // link worker to workspace

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    printf("Worker %d\n", workspace->tid);
    int max = workspace->points_generated;
    unsigned int seed = workspace->seed;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
        float point_x = (float)rand_r(&seed) / RAND_MAX * 2.0 - 1.0;
        float point_y = (float)rand_r(&seed) / RAND_MAX * 2.0 - 1.0;

        printf("x: %f, y: %f\n", point_x, point_y);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void calculate_circle_area(int total_samples, int no_workers) {
    pthread_t worker_thread[no_workers];
    Workspace workspace;
    workspace.points_generated = total_samples / no_workers;
    workspace.tid = 0;
    workspace.seed = time(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < no_workers; ++i) {
        workspace.tid += 1;
        pthread_create(&worker_thread[i], NULL, worker, &workspace);
        pthread_join(worker_thread[i], NULL);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("usage: ./program [no. of samples] [no. of worker threads]\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else {
        int total_samples = atoi(argv[1]);
        int no_workers = atoi(argv[2]);

        printf("\n");
        calculate_circle_area(total_samples, no_workers);

        printf("\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

This works very partially, it does generate the random numbers and everything is split correctly, but each thread generates the same numbers, each numbers within the threads are different however.

example output for command: ./calc_area 9 3 (generate 9 randoms in total, using 3 threads)

```
Worker 1
x: 0.506291, y: -0.765927
x: -0.941786, y: -0.598265
x: 0.962658, y: -0.609824
Worker 2
x: 0.506291, y: -0.765927
x: -0.941786, y: -0.598265
x: 0.962658, y: -0.609824
Worker 3
x: 0.506291, y: -0.765927
x: -0.941786, y: -0.598265
x: 0.962658, y: -0.609824
```

I want each thread to generate different numbers from each other how can I do that? Thank you

Comment: What do you think the "seed" is supposed to do? Also, if you're running your entire work while holding a mutex, a single thread will be much faster then multiple threads.

Comment: [man rand_r](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rand_r): If rand_r() is called with the same initial value for the integer pointed to by seedp, and that value is not modified between calls, then the same pseudo-random sequence will result.

Comment: You should probably pass `workspace->seed` directly to each `rand_r` call rather than using a local copy. So that the shared seed can be updated and used by each thread.

Comment: OT: It's kind of pointless to have multiple threads with a big fat lock around the whole thing that essentially serialises every thread. That could be because this is an academic exercise but you may want to check that you have satisfied the original requirements fully.

Answer (score 0):

Since you included the multithreading tag, here is a solution using Ada.
In this case the random number seeds are reset by each task (i.e. thread) ensuring that the seeds are different and therefore the random number sequence is different.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;               use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Numerics.Float_Random; use Ada.Numerics.Float_Random;
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;         use Ada.Float_Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;       use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   type Point is record
      X : Float;
      Y : Float;
   end record;

   procedure Print (Item : Point) is
   begin
      Put ("X:");
      Put (Item => Item.X, Fore => 2, Aft => 4, Exp => 0);
      Put (" Y:");
      Put (Item => Item.Y, Fore => 2, Aft => 4, Exp => 0);
      New_Line;
   end Print;

   type Point_Array is array (Positive range <>) of Point;

   task type worker is
      entry Set_Num (Count : Positive);
      entry Report;
   end worker;

   task body worker is

      Seed       : Generator;
      Num_Points : Positive;
   begin
      Reset (Seed);
      accept Set_Num (Count : Positive) do
         Num_Points := Count;
      end Set_Num;

      declare
         Buf : Point_Array (1 .. Num_Points);
      begin

         for I in Buf'Range loop
            Buf (I).X := Random (Seed) * 2.0 - 1.0;
            Buf (I).Y := Random (Seed) * 2.0 - 1.0;
         end loop;
         accept Report;
         for I in Buf'Range loop
            Print (Buf (I));
         end loop;
         New_Line;
      end;

   end worker;

   type Team is array (Positive range <>) of worker;
   Num_Tasks : Positive;
   Num_Rand  : Positive;

begin
   Put ("Enter the number of task: ");
   Get (Num_Tasks);
   Put ("Enter the number of results per task: ");
   Get (Num_Rand);
   declare
      Workers : Team (1 .. Num_Tasks);
   begin
      for I in Workers'Range loop
         Workers (I).Set_Num (Num_Rand);
      end loop;
      for I in Workers'range loop
         Put_Line ("Worker" & I'Image);
         Workers (I).Report;
         delay 0.01;
      end loop;
   end;

end Main;
```

The output for an execution using 6 tasks and 4 results per task is:

```
Enter the number of task: 6
Enter the number of results per task: 4
Worker 1
X: 0.7487 Y:-0.6497
X:-0.9634 Y: 0.6317
X:-0.9189 Y: 0.8070
X: 0.8837 Y:-0.3839

Worker 2
X: 0.6409 Y:-0.4913
X:-0.0185 Y: 0.1078
X:-0.6408 Y:-0.9719
X:-0.6199 Y: 0.9301

Worker 3
X:-0.9440 Y: 0.1089
X:-0.1354 Y:-0.3133
X: 0.8479 Y:-0.7389
X: 0.8399 Y: 0.4826

Worker 4
X:-0.9165 Y:-0.3652
X: 0.4137 Y:-0.6292
X: 0.6467 Y: 0.9344
X: 0.2898 Y: 0.1059

Worker 5
X: 0.8818 Y:-0.3551
X:-0.5161 Y:-0.5251
X:-0.6831 Y:-0.0531
X: 0.8207 Y:-0.7419

Worker 6
X: 0.2529 Y:-0.9385
X: 0.5640 Y: 0.3365
X:-0.4477 Y: 0.1642
X: 0.8230 Y: 0.8284
```